# Can't see full Error log in kaggle Console

Tags: python, kaggle

I'm using a Kaggle Kernel to make a python Script. When runing it, Errors pop up as expected. The problem is that for some reason, I can't see the full Error, it just shows a line. That makes it impossible to debug.

To make it clear, my question is not about solving the Error that is raised, I want to see the full Error. In other words, i want to read what comes after the "but - " in the image.

[Here you can see I can only read the first words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui7H4.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it might be easiest to flip it to a notebook (in the editor, File -> Kernel Type -> Notebook), run the cell, and then flip it back to a script (in the editor, File -> Kernel Type -> Script) when you're ready.